# WPF NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, wpf, nullreferenceexception

I am having trouble with some WPF code. This is code I was using previously with another project and it ran fine. I have a class Dots.cs which is a dependency the project containing my main Window1.xaml.cs.

Within Dots.cs I have this function:

```
    public void MakeDraggable(Canvas theCanvas)
    {
        _canvas = theCanvas;
        _canvas.PreviewMouseDown += DPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
    }
```

I am receiving the InnerException '{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at GraphicsBook.Dot.MakeDraggable(Canvas theCanvas) in ...\Dot.cs:line 261
   at GraphicsBook.Window1..ctor() in...\Window1.xaml.cs:line 47}

The call to the MakeDraggable method within my Window1.xaml.cs is:

```
    myDots = new Dot[3];
    myDots[0] = new Dot(new Point(-40, 60));
    myDots[1] = new Dot(new Point(40, 60));
    myDots[2] = new Dot(new Point(40, -60));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        myDots[i].MakeDraggable(gp);
        gp.Children.Add(myDots[i]);
    }
```

For clarity line 261 in Dot.cs is:

```
_canvas.PreviewMouseDown += DPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
```

And line 47 in Window1.xaml.cs is:

```
myDots[i].MakeDraggable(gp);
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be beneficial to validate the arguments to your method before using them.  This way, you'll know you've got good values.  In your case, there's a good chance that your object gp is null.  You can find that out using a breakpoint.

To make it more robust, you can add an argument check to your MakeDraggable like so:

```
public void MakeDraggable(Canvas theCanvas)
{
    if (theCanvas == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("theCanvas");
    }

    _canvas = theCanvas;
    _canvas.PreviewMouseDown += DPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
}
```

Now if you *ever* call MakeDraggable with null, you'll get the clear Argument Null exception instead of the less descriptive NullReferenceException.

Comment: Thanks that was it! I hadn't set it up properly in my XAML.